# Python Regex capture multiple sections within string

Tags: python, regex

I have string that are always of the format `track-a-b` where `a` and `b` are integers.
For example:
`track-12-29`
`track-1-210`
`track-56-1`

How do I extract `a` and `b` from such strings in python?

Comment: Do you have any code thus far? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just a single string, I would approach this using split:

```
>>> s = 'track-12-29'
>>> s.split('-')[1:]
['12', '29']
```

If it is a multi-line string, I would use the same approach ...

```
>>> s = 'track-12-29\ntrack-1-210\ntrack-56-1'
>>> results = [x.split('-')[1:] for x in s.splitlines()]
[['12', '29'], ['1', '210'], ['56', '1']]
```

Comment: is there a reason `split` is preferred?

Comment: @blue_zinc avoid regexes are error prone and using string methods (`str.split`, etc.) are often faster and more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `re.findall()` with capturing groups:

```
results = [re.findall(r'track-(\d+)-(\d+)', datum) for datum in data]
```